# smooth $C^\infty$ anywhere but analytical $C^{\omega}$ nowhere function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

There is function which is smooth but not analytic in one point. Such as 
$$f(x)=\exp(-1/x^2)$$

Does there exist function that is smooth $C^\infty$ anywhere but analytical $C^{\omega}$ nowhere ?

If exist, give an explicit example. If not, how to prove?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620290/is-it-possible-for-a-function-to-be-smooth-everywhere-analytic-nowhere-yet-tay?rq=1

Comment: Google it. Alternatively, just search this site. Low effort post.