# Do there exist functions which are differentiable everywhere but analytic nowhere?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, reference-request, soft-question

Once upon a time, when the earth was still young and innocent I studied one complex variable. In this course I learned that a function can be complex analytic, but that there are far fewer functions than the real differentiable ones which are complex analytic.

Can we find an example of a function which is real differentiable everywhere but complex analytic nowhere?

If I recall right, the requirements for analyticity of function $x+yi\to u(x,y)+ iv(x,y)$ are known as the Cauchy-Riemann equations:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = 0\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = 0$$

Let us disqualify $z\to \bar z$, it is too uninteresting example.

Comment: $f(z)=\bar{z}$, for example.

Comment: @user10354138 ah yes, i came to think of it right after posting, i will try to edit question. its far too simple now.

Comment: use it or lose it :)

Comment: If you rewrite CR equations in the form $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline z}=0, $$ it will become more apparent why $f(z)=\overline z$ fails to be a solution.

Comment: I think $e^{-x^2}$ is another example.

Comment: @MJD : Mhm, maybe, it will be chirps in quadrature in imaginary direction, no? Quite interesting function.

Comment: @AlvinLepik Probably the course I remember most from all-in-all from those days. :)

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro that is an interesting form, I was not aware of it.

Comment: Then consider $f(z) = |z|^2$, which is complex differentiable only at the origin.

Comment: @GuiseppeNegro But it involves conjugate since $|z|^2=z \cdot \bar z$

Comment: "*real differentiable everywhere but complex analytic nowhere*" --- Since this is rather trivial (conjugation function, as pointed out by @user10354138), I wonder if you were thinking of [real-valued $C^{\infty}$ functions that are nowhere real-analytic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620290/is-it-possible-for-a-function-to-be-smooth-everywhere-analytic-nowhere-yet-tay)?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I was just trying to reformulate it as I realized it was too easy. Hmm, maybe something like that. Wow cool, did you investigate it?

Comment: This is something I collected some literature on during the mid to late 1990s, and I wrote a summary of the topic in May 2002, [here](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=387148) and [here](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=387149).