# Show that there is an infinitely differentiable function f(x), such that the radius of convergence of its Taylor series equals to 0

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

This is an exercise from my introduction to real analysis course, this does not count for marks.
I saw several people said $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty}n!x^{n}$, I mean this power series clearly has a radius of convergence that is 0, but how can one know that it is some function's Taylor series? Or is there any other example? Please advise, thank you.

Comment: See also [620290](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620290/is-it-possible-for-a-function-to-be-smooth-everywhere-analytic-nowhere-yet-tay)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any explicit example but it is well known that there is a $C^{\infty}$ function $f$ with $f^{(n)}(0)=(n!)^{2}$ for  all $n$. [ We can in fact prescribe the derivatives arbitrarily]. Obviously we cannot  define $f$ by the series $\sum (n!)x^{n}$.
The existence of $f$ is special case of Borel's Lemma.