# If a Taylor series agrees with its function in $U$, that function is analytic in $U$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, analytic-functions

Assume that $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ coincides with its Taylor series centered at a point $p\in U$ on an open set $U$, i.e.

$$\exists p\in U, \forall x\in U, f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(n)}(p)}{k!}(x-p)^n.$$

Is $f$ analytic on $U$?

That is:

$$\forall p\in U, \exists \varepsilon>0, \forall x\in \mathbb{R}, |p-x|<\varepsilon\Rightarrow f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(n)}(p)}{k!}(x-p)^n?$$

Comment: That counterexample doesn't work - if the domain of the bump function intersects $U$, then $f$ isn't equal everywhere in $U$ to its Taylor series at the initial $p$.

Comment: I've submitted an edit to the question to make clear that the $p$ in the first equation is different from the $p$ in the second equation.

Comment: @paulgarrett, It's true that for any set $U$ and point $p \in U$, there is a function $f$ which is equal to its Taylor series in a different neighbourhood $U'$ of $p$, but isn't analytic everywhere in $U$ (i.e. there's a bump function nearby the basepoint). But the question is asking, *given* that $f$ is equal to its Taylor series everywhere in $U$, i.e. *given* that $U$ is chosen so that $f$ doesn't have a bump function in $U$, does $f$ has to be analytic in $U$?

Comment: Related: smooth functions cannot have everywhere converging analytic series without being analytic themselves https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620290/is-it-possible-for-a-function-to-be-smooth-everywhere-analytic-nowhere-yet-tay

Comment: Ah, ok, if the power series is not only convergent in $U$, but also converges to $f$ in $U$, then, yes, I agree $f$ is analytic in $U$. Convergence alone is not enough... I'll delete my earlier comments, which have become irrelevant... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes, though it should be pointed out that the answer to your title's question is NO: "analytic at a point" does not imply "analytic on $U$" (bump functions being an obvious counterexample). But this doesn't contradict what I'm about to say because your hypothesis is doesn't just say "analytic at a point"; it is actually stronger than that.

Anyway, just to be explicit, @paul garrett's comment that "Analyticity at one point, or even on a non-trivial open, does not magically *force* analyticity anywhere else" is definitely correct, but again, this doesn't answer the question, and it also doesn't contradict what I'm about to say, because your assumption is stronger.

---

To prove this, let us fix a point $p\in U$ as in the hypothesis. Now, define $\rho:= \sup\limits_{x\in U}|x-p|$. Then,

- $0<\rho\leq \infty$
- $U$ is contained in the open interval $(p-\rho,p+\rho)$ (which we interpret as $\Bbb{R}$ in case $\rho=\infty$). This is because if $x\in U$, then $x\in [p-\rho,p+\rho]$ definitely, but because of openness of $U$, we must actually have $x\in I=(p-\rho,p+\rho)$, otherwise it would contradict the definition of $\rho$ as a supremum.
- The formal series $S(X)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(p)}{n!}X^n$ has radius of convergence $\geq \rho$ (why?).

So, the function $\phi:I\to\Bbb{R}$, $\phi(x):=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(p)}{n!}(x-p)^n$ is well-defined (i.e the series converges) and $\phi|_U=f|_U$ by hypothesis. So, as long as we show $\phi$ is analytic on the interval $I$, it follows that $\phi|_U$ is analytic (restriction of analytic functions to open sets is again analytic simply by looking at the definition) and hence $f|_U$ is analytic. In short, we just have to show "functions defined by convergent power series are analytic as long as we're within the radius of convergence".

The idea of the proof is just to rearrange a double sum, and we can do this as long as the series in question converge absolutely. For notational convenience, let's define $a_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(p)}{n!}$. Now, fix a point $x_0\in I$, denote $r_0=|x_0-p|$ and fix an $r$ such that $0<r<\frac{\rho- r_0}{2}$.

Recall that we can calculate the derivatives $\phi^{(n)}(x_0)$ using term-by-term differentiation. We now show that the the series centered at $x_0$ has radius of convergence $\geq r$:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left|\frac{\phi^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}\right|r^n&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left|\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(m+n)!}{m!}a_{m+n}(x_0-p)^m\right|r^n\\
&\leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(m+n)!}{n!m!}|a_{m+n}|r_0^mr^n\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{l=0}^k\frac{k!}{l!(k-l)!}|a_k|r_0^{k-l}r^{l}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}|a_k|(r_0+r)^k\\
&<\infty,
\end{align}
whereby in the middle I rearranged the terms (which is valid since we're dealing with non-negative terms), and I used the usual binomial theorem, and finally since $r_0+r<\rho$, it follows the series is indeed finite, and hence the formal series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\phi^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}X^n$ has radius of convergence $\geq r$.

Now, we repeat the same calculation, but this time without absolute values, and we rearrange the double sum. The triangle inequality shows that any point $x$ such that $|x-x_0|\leq r$ actually belongs to $I$. Now, for such values of $x$, we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\phi^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\left(\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(m+n)!}{m!}a_{m+n}(x_0-p)^m\right)(x-x_0)^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(m+n)!}{n!m!}a_{m+n}(x_0-p)^m(x-x_0)^n\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{l=0}^k\frac{k!}{l!(k-l)!}a_k(x_0-p)^{k-l}(x-x_0)^{l}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k(x-p)^k\\
&=:\phi(x)
\end{align}
In the middle we were able to rearrange the double sum from $(n,m)$ to $(k,l)$ because we established absolute convergence in the previous paragraph.
So, for each $x_0\in I$, we have proven the existence of an $r>0$ such that for all $|x-x_0|\leq r$, $\phi(x)$ does indeed equal its Taylor series centered at $x_0$. Hence, $\phi$ is analytic on $I$. This completes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series), yes, $f$ is analytic everywhere on the interval where it is equal to its Taylor series (see the end of the introductory paragraph). I'm not sure how to prove it, but I guess convergent infinite sums of polynomials just happen to be analytic.