# On which sets can a function have zero derivatives?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, reference-request

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be infinitely differentiable not identically zero. Let $S_f=\{ x : f^{(n)}(x)=0 \ \forall n\in\mathbb{N} \}$. $S_f$ can be non empty e.g. $e^{-1/x^2}$-like examples. In fact, $S_f$ can contain an interval (integrate the previous example). Clearly $S$ is closed. Is there an example of a closed proper subset $K$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $K$ is not $S_f$ for any $f$?

We can combine my two examples to make a lot of closed sets, but its not so obvious how to make sure a function with $S_f$ equal to the cantor set.

If such a $K$ exists, is there another way to characterise which sets $S_f$ can be?

Comment: Possibly some of the results and literature cited in Andrés E. Caicedo's answer to [Is it possible for a function to be smooth everywhere, analytic nowhere, yet Taylor series at any point converges in a nonzero radius?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/630687/13130) might help, but I don't have time to give this much thought right now. *(moments later, after another search)* Better yet, see the mathoverflow question [Smooth functions with zeros of infinite order on a closed set](https://mathoverflow.net/q/388874/15780).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This can be done iteratively. Choose a cover of the complement of $K$
> by a countable family of open balls $_$. For each of the open
> balls, consider a smooth function $_$ such that
> $\{_>0\}$=$_$. Then for $_$ going to zero fast enough,
> $\sum_n __$ and all its derivatives converges uniformly, so
> the limit exists, is smooth, and the derivatives are the sum are the
> sum of the derivatives. In particular, they all vanish on $K$

Due to [Pierre PC](https://mathoverflow.net/q/388895)

Answer (score 0):

Given any closed interval $I=[a,b]$, the function:
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
e^{\frac{-1}{(x-a)^2}}, & x < a \\
0, & a\le x\le b \\
e^{\frac{-1}{(x-b)^2}}, & x > b 
\end{cases}
$$
has $f^{(n)}=0,\forall x\in I, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$
i.e, $S_f=I$

This work due the fact that all derivaties of $e^{-\frac{1}{(x-p)^2}}$ vanishes at $x=p$.